# Angular Project and context root

Tags: angular, maven, was

I have built an Angular 6 project as a Maven project and packaged into WAR.

So when the project is deployed, the server (WAS) puts all the compiled files into the target folder. The context root is set to target/MyApp.

When I try to load it, I use the URL `localhost:9080/target/MyApp/index.html`, but it throws an error saying it couldn't find `runtime.js` and few other js files mentioned in `index.html`, although those files are in the same folder as `index.html` i.e. `target/MyApp/..` The server is actually looking for those files in the root folder.

So, I can access those files as `localhost:9080/target/MyApp/runtime.js` but the server doesn't look into this folder. What changes should I make to make this working?

Below is my compiled `index.html`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

The error I see is `GET http://localhost:9081/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED`

Answer (score 1):

Angular needs to know what the base URL is.

Try changing the *index.html* file so that `<base href="/target/MyApp/">` points to the current URL.

As mentioned in the comments, you can set the base URL via the command line.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#base-tag-handling-in-indexhtml

```
# Sets base tag href to /myUrl/ in your index.html
ng build --base-href /myUrl/
```

Comment: Can I do something in pom or server instead of changing index.html? Because changing index.html will cause issues when I try to run the app locally.

Also, why does it work when I run it locally but doesn't work with WAS?

Comment: You can change the base href by using the `--base-href` flag and specifying a string. See more info here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#base-tag-handling-in-indexhtml